# Which tool is good, phonetisaurus or logios with cmudict-0.7b?

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

As phonetisaurus is not maintained and new online LM Tool v3 is using logios.

Question is which tool is recommended for phonetic dictionary generation?

If logios, then anyone knows any good document about the procedure ?

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, I am using phonetisaurus now, but as it is not maintained, what is recomondation for future?  

If you see http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html  on this page it is mentioned :
""The new version of lmtool has been reorganized internally to make use of the Logios package. This will make lmtool easier to maintain in the future and will allow it to take advantage of ongoing development in Logios. ""

I am confused here little bit. I want to make use of  latest cmudict-0.7b.
What is the problem with logios ?

Comment: In the future we will have a phonetisaurus replacement for g2p. Logios is closed source, so I can not recommend it.

Comment: Ok got it. I will continue with phonetisaurus for now.